# Associate Load of List in Controller for Google Map?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm stuck in a situation where i need to Get the List in My Controller but now Currently I'm using A Kendo Grid to fetch the list that will be used in my Google Maps

Now my question are

1. How can i associate the LoadWorkerList in Controller Directly in my
   Googlemap and Add it as a Marker?

   2.How can i make A List of Markers on my Screen??

This is my Javascript for my Google Maps :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });
    }
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var address = $('#workerGrid').find("input[name=shiftDay]");
        alert(address);
        $.each(address, function () {
            var currVal = $(this).val();
            address.each(function () {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal
                        });
                        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                            map: map,
                            radius: 16093,    // 10 miles in metres
                            fillColor: '#AA0000'
                        });

                        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'center');


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));

                        address.push(marker);


                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
        return true;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
        codeAddress();

    }

</script>
```

and this is my Controllers Code :

```
public JsonResult LoadWorkerList()
        {
            var workerList = new List<Worker_Address>();

            // check if search string has value
            // retrieve list of workers filtered by search criteria
            var list = (from a in db.Worker_Address
                        where a.LogicalDelete == false
                        select a).ToList();



            List<WorkerAddressInfo> wlist = new List<WorkerAddressInfo>();
            foreach (var row in list)
            {
                WorkerAddressInfo ci = new WorkerAddressInfo
                {
                    ID = row.ID,
                    Worker_ID = row.WorkerID,
                    AddressLine1 = row.Address_Line1 + " " + row.Address_Line2+ " " +row.City + " "+ GetLookupDisplayValById(row.State_LookID),
                    LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete

                };
                wlist.Add(ci);
            }


            return Json(wlist.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.AddressLine1), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Woah! Since when does Javascript have generics? `new List<Worker_Address>()`

Comment: @Chloe I think he doesn't explained well what he is using (it seems like C#) or used the incorrect tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google APIs work with geolocations, so you should store lat and lon values (or you might generate them dynamic everytime but it will be a slow process). Assuming you did that as a utility work, then you can create the location list for javascript from backend. At the end it should be like this:

```
var locations = [
      ['<h4>Worker Name 1</h4>', lat1, lon1],
      ['<h4>Worker Name 2</h4>', lat2, lon2],
      ...
      ['<h4>Worker Name N</h4>', latN, lonN]
    ];
```

And then add them to your map:

```
   var marker;
    var markers = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

markers.push(marker);
```

Comment: sir i need to add a Panel that will show the list of markers active in google map

Comment: I'm confused, do you want a text list like A .... B.... or google map with markers? That would be great if you could explain visually

Comment: Actually what im trying to do is like the list http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/

I want to make a list that will display and undisplay when the marker is out of bounds

Comment: That seems a lot of hard work :D Maybe you can create the list by yourself calling from database? That seams easier than getting whole data from map. And then you can bind click of your list item with focusing spesific marker on map. This way you can display about each worker too.

Comment: and sir kuzgun i'm still scratching my head on how to make a list like the one ive shown you :) dont know if its a div or whatever :D

Comment: but you got all the data in db why scratching head :) one repeater, some sql, some jquery then you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I Forgot to mention that yesterday i Solved Question number 1 by adding a getJSON function

```
function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function (address) {
            $.each(address, function () {
                var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal
                        })
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);
                    }
                    else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                        setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Now i need to Find on how a Panel inside the Google map will display the Markers active on Screen in Google Maps